# REST Protocol for searching and filtering

Tags: rest, http

The standard REST verb for returning a value GET can take different parameters to select what to "get". Often there is one that takes an id to get a single value, and often some sort of search criteria to get a list.

Is there a standard way to specify the filtering and sorting of the data that is being searched for? For example, if I have an invoice record I'd like to write a GET query that says "give me all invoices for customer 123, with total > $345 and return in descending order of date".

If I were writing this myself I'd have something like:

GET [http://example.com/mydata?query="customer=123&&total>345.00"&order="date"](http://example.com/mydata?query=%22customer=123&&total%3E345.00%22&order=%22date%22)

(Note I didn't urlencode the url for clarity, though obviously that is required in practice, but I hope you get what I mean.)

I can certainly write something for this, but I am wondering if there is a standardized way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a standard way to specify the filtering and sorting of the data that is being searched for?

Not that I'm aware of.

Note that HTTP doesn't really have queries (yet); HTTP has resource identifiers.

We've got a standard for resource identifiers ([RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986)) and a standard for URI templates ([RFC 6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570)) that describes how to produce a range of identifiers via variable expansion.

But as far as I can tell there is no published "standard" that automatically transforms a URI into a SQL query.

It's possible that one of the "convention over configuration" frameworks (ex: Rails) might have something useful here, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Apologies, my question wasn't super clear, I wasn't looking to automatically transform to SQL per se, but just to have something of similar expressiveness as SQL. I modified the question.